# Не выделяется память под передаваемый в функцию элемент

Tags: c, функции, указатели, память

Дело в том, что при попытке выделить память под curList у меня вылетает программа. В функцию эта переменная передается со значением NULL. При дебаге GDB выводит следующее: "Program recieved signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault". Однако в предыдущей работе у меня была такая же функция, и такой проблемы не было. Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

```
PConst createNode(char **str_array, PConst NewNode, PLOM curList, PLOMHead curHead, int i)
    {
        PLOM helpList;
        int slen;
        char *endOfString;

        NewNode = (PConst)realloc(NewNode, (i+1)*sizeof(struct constellation));

        slen = strlen(str_array[0]);
        NewNode[i].Name = (char*)malloc((slen+1)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(&NewNode[i].Name, &str_array[0], slen+1);

        slen = strlen(str_array[1]);
        NewNode[i].Abbreviation = (char*)malloc((slen+1)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(&NewNode[i].Abbreviation, &str_array[1], slen+1);

        slen = strlen(str_array[2]);
        curList->Month = (char*)malloc((slen+1)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(&curList->Month, &str_array[2], slen+1);

        addMonth(curHead, curList);

        helpList = curHead->first;
        do
        {
            if ((strcmp(helpList->Month, curList->Month)==0))
                NewNode[i].Month = helpList;

            helpList = helpList->next;
        } while (helpList != curHead->first);

        slen = strlen(str_array[3]);
        endOfString = str_array[3]+slen;
        NewNode[i].area = strtol(str_array[3], &endOfString, 10);

        slen = strlen(str_array[4]);
        endOfString = str_array[4]+slen;
        NewNode[i].latitude[0] = strtol(str_array[4], &endOfString, 10);

        slen = strlen(str_array[5]);
        endOfString = str_array[5]+slen;
        NewNode[i].latitude[1] = strtol(str_array[5], &endOfString, 10);

        checkAndSwap(&NewNode[i].latitude[0], &NewNode[i].latitude[1]);

        slen = strlen(str_array[6]);
        endOfString = str_array[6]+slen;
        NewNode[i].max_declination = strtof(str_array[6], &endOfString);

        slen = strlen(str_array[7]);
        endOfString = str_array[7]+slen;
        NewNode[i].min_declination = strtof(str_array[7], &endOfString);

        slen = strlen(str_array[8]);
        endOfString = str_array[8]+slen;
        NewNode[i].bs_qntt = strtol(str_array[8], &endOfString, 10);

        curList->next = curHead->first;

        return NewNode;
    }
```

typedef'ы и структуры выглядят вот так:

```
struct constellation
{
    char *Name;
    char *Abbreviation;
    struct listOfMonths *Month;
    int area;
    int latitude[2];
    float max_declination;
    float min_declination;
    int bs_qntt;
};

struct listOfMonths
{
    char *Month;
    struct listOfMonths *next;
};

struct lOMHead
{
    struct listOfMonths *first;
    struct listOfMonths *last;
};

typedef struct constellation *PConst;
typedef struct listOfMonths *PLOM;
typedef struct lOMHead *PLOMHead;
```

В main функция вызывается вот так:

```
int main()
{
    enum {max_name_len = 512, max_firm_name = 50};

    PConst cnstlltns = NULL;
    PLOMHead head;
    PLOM currentLOM = NULL;

    int i = 0, m;
    char **help_str;
    char s1[max_name_len];

    FILE *input = fopen("CSV.txt","r");
    if (!input)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Nothing to read!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    head = makeHead();

    while (!feof(input))
    {
        fgets(s1, max_name_len, input);
        help_str = simpleSplit(s1);

        cnstlltns = createNode(help_str, cnstlltns, currentLOM, head, i);

        cnstlltns = realloc(cnstlltns,(i+1)*sizeof(struct constellation));

        for (m = 2; m < 6; m++)
            free(help_str[m]);
        free(help_str);

        i++;
    }

    fclose(input);
    printf("Success in reading data. Start the program.\n\n");

    mainMenu(cnstlltns, i, head);

    free(cnstlltns);

    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую я с помощью GNU GCC Compiler в CodeBlocks 16.1, операционная система - Win 7. Надеюсь на вашу отзывчивость.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в функцию переменную `currentLOM` с значением `NULL`, а в функции обращаетесь к ней:

```
curList->Month = ...
```

как будто она на что-то указывает.

Comment: То есть сначала необходимо выделить память под саму переменную?

Comment: @Xiamera конечно

Comment: Вам будет гораздо проще воспользоваться отладчиком. Каковы значения `helpList->Month` и `curList->Month` перед выполнение строки, приводящей к ошибке?

Comment: иногда при попытке узнать значение helpList->Month вылетает ошибка "Cannot access memory at address 0x0"

Comment: @Xiamera Значит нужно смотреть на значение переменной `helpList`.

Comment: она становится равной NULL при операции helpList = helpList->next;. Просто предыдущая работа была по кольцевым спискам, а эта - нет. Необходимо изменить условие

Comment: @Xiamera `} while (helpList && helpList != curHead->first);`?

Comment: да. В этом заключалась проблема